# Error in mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct) : Variable(s) ‘Methode’ of class ‘integer’ is/are not contained as a factor in ‘model’

Tags: r, lme4, anova

I don't get why it does not work here is my code:

```
     library(lme4,multcomp)

tijd <- c(7.667, 9.5, 6.467, 10.033, 9.767, 29.133, 15.933, 8.1, 8.6, 
          12.3, 5.867, 13.667, 12.933, 11.933, 27.2, 11.567, 10.9, 12.567, 
          9.033, 12.6, 13.133, 17.067, 14.333, 15.2, 9.1, 9.167, 8.4, 11.4, 
          18.467, 15.633, 10.4, 10.767, 12.7, 7.667, 9.867, 36.167, 20.4, 
          33.8, 15.767, 20.1, 10.533, 17.7, 62.667, 21.133, 40.133, 9.2, 
          19.467, 7.667, 8.867, 20.333, 14.367, 10.167, 28.4, 11.367, 10.867, 
          22.1, 24.8, 13.3, 17.067, 10.967, 12.333, 28.867, 21.1)

week <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)

Methode <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 
            4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 
            1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 
            2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)

freq <- c(c(5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
            8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 
            5.9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 5.9, 5.9, 
            5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10))

ID <-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
       8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 
       1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 1, 2, 
       3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

week <- as.factor(week)
Methode <- as.factor(Methode)
ID <- as.factor(ID)


M1 <- lmer(log(tijd) ~ Methode + (1|freq) + (1|week) + (1|ID), data = data)
summary(M1)
anova(M1, type = "III", test = "F")

plot(M1)
plot(cooks.distance(M1))


summary(glht(M1, linfct = mcp(Methode = "Tukey")))
```

Here are the first lines of my dataset: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyXLb.jpg
I am currently working on my bachelor thesis and if you could help me it would be really nice.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi, it is difficult to help you as we don't know what your data look like. Could you edit your post with an exemple of data (i.e. first lines) ? Thanks

Comment: @BastienDucreux I just added an example of the data. If u wonder what the dutch words mean tijd=time (in this experiment the time it takes for a crab to pass an obstacle) and the rest is quite the same in English I think :)

Comment: @user213544 I find it difficult to understand what a MR example is. Maybe you mean this: The experiment is conducted on 8 crabs(ID) treated with different  methods. They then had to do a river parcour in different river flow speeds(frequence) and this for 3 weeks to see the long term effect. Does this make it clearer or do you need reproducible datasets cause i don't know how to do that. My programming skills are limited to some basic R statistical analysis.

Comment: @user213544 Thank you for being patient with me. I think I fixed it there is now a minimal  reproducible example in the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your lmer code, you rely on `data` but you are not converting `data$Methode` to factor, then your code should be :

```
data$week <- as.factor(data$week)
data$Methode <- as.factor(data$Methode)
data$ID <- as.factor(data$ID)

M1 <- lmer(log(tijd) ~ Methode + (1|freq) + (1|week) + (1|ID), data = data)
```

The data you show in your image does not contain the same column name than your lmer code so you will have to pay attention (exemple : frequentie and freq)

Comment: Ooh man what a rookie mistake. Thanks for the help :)